# Magento 1.9.4.2: upgrade Debian from 9 to 10

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7, php-7.3

I own an installation of Magento 1.9.4.2 which is running on Debian 9 with PHP 7.0.

Can I upgrade Debian from 9 to 10 which it will run PHP 7.3?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Whether Magento1.9.4.2 will run at PHP7.3 or Debian 10 supports PHP 7.3?

Comment: If Magento1.9.4.2 will run at PHP7.3 after upgraded Debian from 9 to 10